# Design finite automata for this language

Tags: automata, finite-automata

> L = { w : w ∈ {a, b}* ∧ (u, v, z ∈ {a, b}*) (|u| = 2 ∧ |z| = 2 ∧ w =
>   uvz ∧ u ≠ z)}

Can someone explain me this language? What is w = uvz supposed to mean?

I thought I understood correctly, so the words from this language could be for example: ε, aaab, aaba, bbaa, bbba...

Comment: "w = uvz" means that w is the concatenation of u, v and z.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the words I can create with this language are: ε, aaab, aaba, bbaa, bbba... ?

Comment: Useful examples start at larger lengths, but yes, those are all words of length at most four. Except the empty word, which is not in L.